# Error connecting to postgresql when using flask

Tags: python, postgresql, flask

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify
from flask import request
from slotscal import results
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
import time
app = Flask(__name__)


app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI']= 'postgresql://postgres:test123@localhost:5432/flask'

db=SQLAlchemy(app)
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/hamza/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py", line 1094, in create_all
    self._execute_for_all_tables(app, bind, 'create_all')
  File "/home/hamza/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py", line 1086, in _execute_for_all_tables
    op(bind=self.get_engine(app, bind), **extra)
  File "/home/hamza/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py", line 1017, in get_engine
    return connector.get_engine()
  File "/home/hamza/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py", line 592, in get_engine
    sa_url = make_url(uri)
  File "/home/hamza/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/url.py", line 694, in make_url
    return _parse_rfc1738_args(name_or_url)
  File "/home/hamza/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/url.py", line 755, in _parse_rfc1738_args
    raise exc.ArgumentError(
sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Could not parse rfc1738 URL from string 'postgresql:/test123@localhost/flask'
```

Comment: See docs [Postgres-psycopg2](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/dialects/postgresql.html#module-sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.psycopg2) for correct URL.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver Same error.

Comment: You need to add your change as update to the question.

Comment: Sorry tried reinstallin  psycogp2 with the prerequisites sudo apt install libpq-dev python3-dev and it worked. Thanks. You should answer this question.

Answer (score 0):

The connection string has to be a libpq connection string, whose syntax [is documented in the PostgreSQL documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-connect.html#LIBPQ-CONNSTRING).

If you use the URL form, you have to stick to RFC 1738. In particular, you need two slashes after `postgresql:`:

```
postgresql://test123@localhost/flask
```